# Does Turn the Unholy work on fallen Celestials?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, class-feature, paladin, divine

The description for the Oath of Devotion Paladin feature [Turn Unholy](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/paladin#DevotionChannelDivinity) mentions fiends and undead, but what about corrupted celestials that still have the celestial type (such as the [Radiant Idol](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/487750-radiant-idol) in *Eberron: Rising from the Last War*)? Are they considered fiends for the purpose of the ability?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### As written, Turn Unholy does not work on Radiant Idol.

As you quoted in the question body, Turn Unholy is effective on fiends and undeads:

> Each fiend or undead that can see or hear you within 30 feet of you must make a Wisdom saving throw.

Since a Radiant Idol is a celestial, this particular Paladin's channel divinity feature cannot work on this monster.

The description of the monster says:

> A radiant idol was an angel that was banished from the celestial realm of Syrania and cast down to the Material Plane.

and

> **Fallen Angels.** The insatiable hunger to be adored can transform a fallen angel, physically and mentally.

*Fallen Angel* is not a creature type, the Radiant Idol is still a celestial. This is coherent with the description of this monster type in the introduction of the MM (emphasis mine):

> Celestials are creatures native to the Upper Planes. Many of them are the servants of deities, employed as messengers or agents in the mortal realm and throughout the planes. Celestials are good by nature, so **the exceptional celestial who strays from a good alignment is a horrifying rarity**. [...]

#### A DM may overrule this.

As usual, the DM could rule that Turn Unholy works also on Radiant Idols or other fallen celestials. But I think that this must be properly handled, determining what is a *fallen celestial*, and just do not let Turn Unholy work also on *all* celestials.